# how to automatically and periodically upload a file from a windows machine to an external MySql DB?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I have a software running on my windows that generates a CSV file every day, and updates this file every 5 minutes and puts the updated variables in a CSV file of the day.  For example:

```
Folder-Month-1/
---1.csv
---2.ccsv
... etc

Folder-Month-2/
---1.csv
.... etc
```

How can I periodically push those CSV files into an external DB such as MySQL. in a form in which I can access all of the data in a single DB?

Answer (score 0):

It might be run by default OS scheduler or from your script. For Windows it's `Task Scheduler` and for Python it could be `APScheduler`.